# How do I get the output of print and read in one line?

Tags: fortran

I have the following code

```
program calc
   implicit none

   real :: num1
   print *, 'Enter first number: '
   read(*,*) num1
   print *, num1
end program calc
```

However, the print and the input come in different lines

```
Output
Enter first number: 
<Number that I input>
```

Is there anyway to make them appear on the same line?

Comment: You need to use non-advancing output, as shown in answer to the linked question.